# Can I open local .doc file in Google Docs without logging in Google account?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api, doc

I have .doc file on my hard drive. I want to open this document in Google Docs. But if there is no Google account, can I handle it ? And is there any solution to open .doc file without MS Office ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a google account to upload the .doc file so it can be viewed (or converted to a Google Document and edited). Other ways to view it might be to use a different word processor like [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) (open source and can work with .doc files)

Answer (score 0):

1) I am not sure that you can open a doc file without logging in with your account.
And FYI - Google Docs has been replaced by Google Drive.

2)There are many doc supporting file browsers. One popular option is Libre Office (earlier open office)

Comment: I want to open .doc file without any programs or browsers. The task is, i don't know user have MS office, or Google Chrome. Because of that i need to open it in web

Comment: There might be similar solutions available online. Google would help.

Answer (score -1):

With [Google Drive viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) without logging Google Account, you can quickly view many file types online, including PDFs, Microsoft Office files, and many image file types.

References [About the Google Drive viewer](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=docs_viewer&answer=2423485)

Comment: i checked for it. But i uploaded it and tried to open, it shows only some unknown signs and words and JS functions, which dont releated with my document.